# Unable to delete commerce users

Tags: sitecore-commerce, user-management

We are using Sitecore Commerce. Users who visit the website can register and are created in the domain `CommerceUsers`.

We moved all data from our PROD to STAGING and this also included users.

Now, in staging, we want to delete all the commerce users but are unable to do so. I have tried

1. Delete user from control panel > user management
2. Delete from asp_users table in the core database
3. Serialized all users, deleted commerceusers from serialization folder and then reverted all users.

When any of those is done, the record is removed from User Management UI.

When user tries to register again, it shows an error :

> The external id for the user CommerceUsers\user@example.com is empty.

or

> Register: An element with the specified key already exists

Then when I check the user management UI or core DB, the user appears there.

How can I permanently delete the 'CommerceUsers'

using Sitecore 8.2 Update 5

Comment: Any errors in log files?

Comment: @AndreiPaliakou No errors in log related to this